# Accumulation points of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering , if a sequence converges does that mean that the sequence have exactly one accumulation point that occurs at it's limit , and if a sequence doesn't converge then it doesn't have any accumulation point ? is that true !

Comment: Looking at your response to the answers so far, maybe you should define accumulation point then.  I think we are assuming a different definition than you.  The terminology is not completely standard.  I am taking accumulation point to mean "subsequential limit".

Comment: If accumulation point means every punctured neighborhood contains a point of the sequence then both of your statements are wrong.  For example, the constant sequence does not have any accumulation points but it converges.

Comment: To give you a little food for thought about accumulation points, and related to your question, you can prove that if a bounded sequence has a unique accumulation point, then it converges to that accumulation point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it converges it has only one accumulation point.  If it doesn't converge it may have any number of accumulation points. Take (1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,..) for an example with 2 accumulation points.  If we want distinct points accumulating use:

$   a(n) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{1}{n}    & : n\equiv0 (2) \\
       1-\frac{1}{n}  & : n\equiv1(2) \\
     \end{array}
   \right.
$

To see that a convergent sequence has exactly one accumulation point:

Your sequence is assumed to converge $a_n \rightarrow c$. Suppose there were two distinct points of accumulation $c,d$.  Then there is some positive distance between $c$ and $d$, $|c-d|=\epsilon >0 $.  By convergence there is some $N$ such that $n \geq N \implies |a_n-c|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.  But then the sequence is always more than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ away from $d$ for $n \geq N$ so $d$ couldn't have been an accumulation point.

Comment: why does that sequence contain 2 accumulation points ? for any neighborhoud N(xn:0.1) it wouldn't contain other points except itself

Comment: I'm using a different definition of accumulation point.  I was using neighborhoods and not deleted neighborhoods, so any neighborhood of the point contains infinitely many points of the sequence.  I'll add a different example.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is an accumulation point of $x_n$ means that every punctured neighborhood of $x$ contains some $x_i$ then neither statement is correct.

For the first statement, note the constant sequence converges yet has no accumulation points.

For the second statement, note a sequence which does not converge can still have accumulation points.  For example any enumeration of the rationals has every real number as an accumulation point.